# How can I tell if an antenna is a dipole antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, datasheet, dipole

**Background**

I'm trying to select an antenna for an FCC/IC-approved cellular module, SIM7000A. Apparently, to meet IC modular certification, you need to select an antenna which has

a) equal or less gain and

b) which is the same type

as the antenna that was used during FCC/IC testing of the module.

**Question**

I'm new to RF wireless and I'm trying to find a dipole antenna, since this is the type of antenna that SIM7000A used in its certification testing. I also know what frequency bands I need and what maximum gain I can have in each band. When I research on Digikey and Mouser there are a lot of antennas which are classified as PCB, or chip, or blade, etc. **My problem is that I can't tell if an antenna is a dipole antenna or not: is there an easy way I can tell?** For most of them, it doesn't mention the words dipole or monopole anywhere on their datasheets.

Comment: don't worry about "dipole" , look for compatibility and compare specs for what you need

Comment: What do you mean by specs @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 ? The only specs I know of are the four LTE bands, the max gain in each band, and that it's a dipole type. There are a few sections in the hardware design guide I don't really understand but I don't think they are antenna parameters.

Comment: well you can't tell by looking at a photo https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1vug_oDvI8KJjSspjq6AgjXXav/SIMCOM-SIM7000A-MINI-PCIE-GPS-Passive-antenna-4G-antenna-USB-adapter-100-New-Original-NBIoT-4G.jpg

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 How can I tell from reading a datasheet? Like this one: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/pulselarsen-antennas/W3022/553-1678-6-ND/2543361

Comment: You wont get very far with this from what you have told me. Get a compatible  antenna with SMA conn and cable

Answer (score 0):

The term **dipole** comes from the fact, that such an antenna has two poles instead of one (monopole).

A monopole looks like a simple pole standing on the ground, which is the reference (other pole) in that case.

In a dipole, you have two poles (often pointing in different directions) referencing each other and no ground plane.

Because of that, a dipole has to be fed with a symmetrical signal, whereas a monopole can be fed with a asymmetrical signal (referenced to ground).